# Barbarian Battlerager Spiked Armor Damage Bonus via RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, damage, barbarian

So the Dwarven Barbarian Battlerager *(SCAG p121)* gets a few class features that specifically tie in to his armor. These allow him to:

1. Make a bonus attack that deals 1d4+Strength piercing damage
2. Automatically deal 3 piercing damage on a successful grapple
3. Deal 3 piercing damage every time he gets hit in melee.

**Is there any way in RAW to enhance the damage for points 1, 2, or 3 via enchanted armor?**

Related: [Barbarian Battlerager Spiked Armor Damage Bonus balance issues](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120415/barbarian-battlerager-spiked-armor-damage-bonus-balance-issues)

Comment: Ok, I'll separate them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### #1 is an attack and can be modified in some ways (such as spells), but not by your armor.

#### #2 and #3, however, are not attacks and there is nothing I know of that could increase their damage.

**Magic Armor** *(DMG p152)* will not increase the damage (or attack roll) for #1.  All it does is provide an AC bonus.
**Magic Weapon** *(DMG p213)* is meant to be used with weapons.  Battleragers *gain the ability* to use spiked armor *as* a weapon *(SCAG p121)*.  This does not actually make spiked armor a weapon.

So by RAW, there is nothing that the spiked armor can do to help your attack.  However, the DM is free to create magic items as treasure as they see fit (unless you are playing in Adventurer's League).

Magic Armor is rare (+1), very rare(+2), or legendary (+3).
Magic Weapons are uncommon(+1), rare (+2), or very rare(+3).

It might be reasonable for a DM to create custom spiked armor with magic spikes which are a Magic Weapon.  It might also be reasonable to combine the 2 magic items by increasing the rarity a step.  So maybe a Legendary Spiked Armor which provides +1 AC and counts as a +2 weapon for attacks and damage (the DM would need to determine whether the +2 affects #2 and #3 or just #1).

Comment: The way to add damage to Battlerager's grapple damage and spiked retribution damage is to apply poison to your spikes. This can be done in an 'enchanted' way by taking three levels of Warlock, weaving chains through your armor spikes and having your Pact of the Chain Imp (invisibly) apply Injury or Contact poison every turn. I think you could even add the Hexblade's Curse proficiency bonus to your poison damage rolls.

Answer (score 2):

## No way to do so currently

There are no magic items in the DMG or adventure modules (as of April 2018) that provide bonuses to Spiked Armor damage.